# How do I get different colors for lines in UVCharts?

Tags: javascript, uvcharts

In UVCharts i am giving in customPallette all the colors,and i am using the Line Chart to display the data,but all the lines in the chart are in same color,but all the values on the line  are changing what ever the colors i am giving in the custom pallete please help me

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3Xdv.png)

Comment: Welcome to _StackOverflow_, you might want to read [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before doing so. Give a bit of context explaining what do you need, what have you tried so far, and why it isn't working as expected (i.e.: error messages, etc.). Also consider taking the time to format your question to be easily understood by readers.